# How to access the elements of an object in the success property of $.ajax method?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
function getReportedInfo(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'includes/get_data.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {id:id},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
};
```

The JSON object returned from the get_data.php script is:

```
{
    id: 5, 
    username: "Anthony", 
    status: "accupied"
}
```

I am able to the length of the data object if I do console.log(data.length). However, I can see the object when I console.log(data) in the success property.
I am not able to access the elements of the data obejct if I do console.log(data.username), doing this displays undefined in the console. 
I created a variable, data1, outside the scope of the function getReportedInfo and assigned the data retrieved via the success property to 
this variable after I tried to display the constents of data1 outside the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like `data` is a string not an object. You can convert this to an object by using [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). Try the following code.

```
function getReportedInfo(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'includes/get_data.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {id:id},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            var dataObject = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(dataObject.username);
        }
    });
};
```

**Edit**

After discussing with OP in comments below, it was determined the object returned `data` was in a structure like the following, and is already in an object form (not a string)

```
{
    "0": {
        id: 5, 
        username: "Anthony", 
        status: "accupied"
    }
}
```

Therefor the following code should work.

```
function getReportedInfo(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'includes/get_data.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {id:id},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data["0"].username);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: when I attempt this solution I get the following error message. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: when I attempt this solution I get the following error message. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: @AndreReid What happens when you `console.log(data)`

Comment: console.log(data) returns the JSON object that I provided in the description.

Comment: This example return an object

Comment: @JoelJaime If it returns an object why is that undefined?

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Its how you do it. Even the `dataType` is set right in this answer, unlike the other answer which is merely a duplicate of this answer.

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but will a datatype of json have a problem if the server is retuning a string but doesn't send content-type of json?

Comment: @ Charlie Fish I am not sure why it is undefined. But while I was searching for a solution, I do not remember seeing an instance where the someone accessed an element of the object returned via the success property of the $ajax method.

Comment: @AndreReid You can totally access the data returned in the success property function. What happens when you run `console.log(typeof data);`?

Comment: @ Charlie Fish console.log(typeof data); returns an object

Comment: @AndreReid Super strange... what happens if you `console.log(Object.keys(data));`?

Comment: @ Charlie Fish When I do console.log(Object.keys(data)); I get  ["0"]. And 
 when I expand this object I get 0: "0" length: 1__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: @AndreReid What happens if you `console.log(data["0"].username)`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161764/discussion-between-charlie-fish-and-andre-reid).

Comment: simiply you can get it with data.id , data.username and data.status.

Comment: @Charlie Fish Doing this, console.log(data["0"].username) displays the username of the person

Comment: @AndreReid Awesome!!! I will update my answer then. Not sure the exact reason for that. Glad it's working now!

Comment: @AndreReid Just updated my answer. Consider accepting and up-voting if it helped you. Happy coding!!

Answer (score -2):

If in php your return like this way

```
<?php

echo json_encode($array);
// or 
return json_encode($array);
```

In JavaScript you can use it as you try to use, now, apparently you are not returning a JSON even though you are indicating it in the request, in this case it uses parse:

```
function getReportedInfo(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'includes/get_data.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { id:id },
        success: function(data) {
            var response = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(response.id); // return 5
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Also set the JSON headers, which makes the browser to know it is JSON. `header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);`

Comment: @Joel Jaime I get the following error when I attempt this solution.  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>). And and the end of get_data.php, I have the following echo json_encode($array);